# pass hashmap data from an activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i just tried to pass values of av hash map to another activity in my code  ExpListViewAdapterWithCheckbox(which  extends from BaseExpandableListAdapter)  .

```
[enter image description here][1]
    HashMap<Integer, boolean[]> fileList = mChildCheckStates;
    Intent intent = new Intent(ExpListViewAdapterWithCheckbox.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("hashMap", fileList);
    startActivity(intent);
```

But it is giving and error saying that **"can not resolve constructor intent"**

**following is the full code**

```
public class ExpListViewAdapterWithCheckbox extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{


private Context mContext;

private HashMap<String, List<String>> mListDataChild;

private ArrayList<String> mListDataGroup;

public HashMap<Integer, boolean[]> mChildCheckStates;

public boolean[] getChecked;

private ChildViewHolder childViewHolder;
private GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;
private String groupText;
private String childText;


public ExpListViewAdapterWithCheckbox(Context context, ArrayList<String> listDataGroup, HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild) {

    mContext = context;
    mListDataGroup = listDataGroup;
    mListDataChild = listDataChild;

    mChildCheckStates = new HashMap<Integer, boolean[]>();
}

public int getNumberOfCheckedItemsInGroup(int mGroupPosition) {
    boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
    int count = 0;
    if (getChecked != null) {
        for (int j = 0; j < getChecked.length; ++j) {
            if (getChecked[j] == true)
                count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return mListDataGroup.size();
}

@Override
public String getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return mListDataGroup.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}


@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    groupText = getGroup(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);

        groupViewHolder = new GroupViewHolder();

        groupViewHolder.mGroupText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);

        convertView.setTag(groupViewHolder);
    } else {

        groupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    groupViewHolder.mGroupText.setText(groupText);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return mListDataChild.get(mListDataGroup.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public String getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return mListDataChild.get(mListDataGroup.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final int mGroupPosition = groupPosition;
    final int mChildPosition = childPosition;

    childText = getChild(mGroupPosition, mChildPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();

        childViewHolder.mChildText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        childViewHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lstcheckBox);

        convertView.setTag(R.layout.list_item, childViewHolder);

    } else {

        childViewHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView
                .getTag(R.layout.list_item);
    }

    childViewHolder.mChildText.setText(childText);

    childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    if (mChildCheckStates.containsKey(mGroupPosition)) {

        boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);

        childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(getChecked[mChildPosition]);

    } else {


         getChecked = new boolean[getChildrenCount(mGroupPosition)];

        mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);

        HashMap<Integer, boolean[]> fileList = mChildCheckStates;
        Intent intent = new Intent(ExpListViewAdapterWithCheckbox.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("hashMap", fileList);
        startActivity(intent);


        childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
    }

    childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {

                boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
                getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);

            } else {

                boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
                getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

public final class GroupViewHolder {

    TextView mGroupText;
}

public final class ChildViewHolder {

    TextView mChildText;
    CheckBox mCheckBox;
}
}
```

I am a newbie to android. Please help me on the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try changing this Intent intent = new Intent(ExpListViewAdapterWithCheckbox.this, MainActivity.class); to new intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use intent.putExtra(String, Serializable) - see

```
intent.putExtra("hashMap", fileList);
```

In the receiving activity use

```
 HashMap<Integer, boolean[]> fileList = (Integer, boolean[]) intent.getSerializableExtra("hashMap");
```

And also chnage the below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ExpListViewAdapterWithCheckbox.this, MainActivity.class);
```

To

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: i really aprreciate your help. But the problem is creating when I am initializing the intent. "Intent intent = new Intent(ExpListViewAdapterWithCheckbox.this, MainActivity.class)" – Janitha Prabath Madushanka

Comment: @JanithaPrabathMadushanka happy to help you.!

Answer (score 0):

Java's HashMap class extends the Serializable interface, which makes it easy to add it to an intent, using the Intent.putExtra(String, Serializable) method.

In the activity/service/broadcast receiver that receives the intent, you then call Intent.getSerializableExtra(String) with the name that you used with putExtra.

For example, when sending the intent:

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
hashMap.put("key", "value");
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("map", hashMap);
startActivity(intent);
```

And then in the receiving Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>)intent.getSerializableExtra("map");
    Log.v("HashMapTest", hashMap.get("key"));
}
```

Comment: i really aprreciate your help. But the problem is creating when  I am initializing the intent. "Intent intent = new Intent(ExpListViewAdapterWithCheckbox.this, MainActivity.class)"

Comment: Here, you can not pass ExpListViewAdapterWithCheckbox.this. A adapter class. You have to pass the Activity.class (Your activity where you are attaching adapter).

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance.

Comment: It's my pleasure to do so. But unfortunately I have not earn enough "reputation".to do so.SORRY for that, But appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

new Intent expects first parameter to be of type context and as your ExpListViewAdapterWithCheckbox class is not of type Activity it is not able to get the context.
So you can use app context to achieve the following.